# Visual Studio 2013 Test Explorer Delayed Start

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2013

I have purchased VS2013 and trying to work on an existing project of my own, and I have 201 unit tests written , but when I open the solution in vs2013 and open the Test class and Right Click , the Run Tests option is disabled .. , after 3-4 minutes it automatically gets enabled.

I am not sure what could be the cause.

my machine is : 8GB ; i7 ; 500gb ;250 ssd

any idea ?

Comment: Are these tests MSTest?

Answer (score 3):

If a solution is being loaded afresh in VS then the test engine needs to do a test discovery to detect if there are test methods available for execution. Once this discovery is completed you will see the list of available tests in the "test explorer" tab and the "run tests" option enabled back on in the right click context menu.

You can notice this phase better if you go to the Output->Tests window where you will see the discovery start and stop messages. Post the stop all run test tests related options will be available.

Comment: It could have been the case, but the thing is even if the project has a single test case , that too in a playlist. it takes time. and there is a magnifying lens kind of animation keeps on animating.

Comment: It takes 3 minutes for every time you debug a test case without any code changes. Why test discovery runs every time? and takes too much time even if it is just one unit test case. Contrary if I close solution and reopen the solution and then debug the test case then it works fast without any delay.